# Accessing Facebook Audience Insights breakdown information

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, audience

I'm trying to access FB Audience Insights via Graph API similar to what is shown in the 'Facebook Business' (https://www.facebook.com/business/news/audience-insights).

This looks like it's possible as documented in the Graph API docs page [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/audience-insights-query).

I have seen some similar questions about this, but there seems to be no clear answer, so I decided to write a new one.

What I have currently:

1. by calling `me/adaccounts` I get all ad accounts - accounts are returned successfully
2. by calling `<adAccountId>/customaudiences` I get custom audiences for each ad account - custom audiences are returned successfully
3. by calling `<customAudienceId>?fields=fields=approximate_count,data_source,name,pixel_id,time_content_updated` I get certain info about the specific audience - returns successfully
4. If my understanding is correct (probably not), I should be able to get audience insights with custom audience id, but I can't figure out how to construct the url shown in the docs: `...?fields={fieldname_of_type_AudienceInsightsQuery}`.
   I am interested in all breakdowns but I'm happy to start with demografic information, so I guess something like this `...?fields=age_by_gender`. 
   But as said I'm stuck with what comes in place of `...`

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've been working on a similar problem *all day* and have gotten nowhere. If you ever find the solution, will you post it here please? Thanks, and good luck!

Comment: @Ryan no, still haven't figured it out, but will definitely post an answer if I do, since I have found no correct answer anywhere.

Comment: Response directly from FB: "Audience Insights API is actually in closed beta"

Comment: Thanks for following up! Any idea how to get invited into that beta? :-)

Comment: @ŽviŽdo hi i have nearly the same problem and i can´t find any solution. How i can get directly support by facebook? I ask because you already get a response by facebook

Comment: @Ryan not sure how to get into beta, you would probably have to bug FB or have some connections there.

Comment: @nicoschuck our company and some other company had a meeting with FB together, but it was totally for a different reasons, I asked our guys present to show them this question :)